# When i put my html file online it doesn't recognise my png file

Tags: html

https://apollo11mission.000webhostapp.com/new%202.html

Somehow my Nasa picture doesn't show up while it shows up when opened offline.
Can somebody help me? I know it might have something to do with putting the image between the header colums. This is my first day working with html so please be kind.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Titel test </title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#fdff00">
<h1> <img src="nasa.png" width=110px height=92px> Apollo 11 mission </h1> 
<img src="as16-113-18339-orig.jpg" width="50%" height="85%" >
<img src="Apollo11.jpg" width="50%" height="85%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's looking the HTML and PNG file on the same folder

Comment: @Tommie Olislagers is the PNG file in the same directory as the HTML file?

Comment: @Eli Yes it is. As seen here. http://imgur.com/a/5AzLo

Comment: the file name is case sensitive so you have to use `Nasa.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is case-sensitivity.

The N from the word Nasa needs to be capitalized. I tried it on your link using developer tools, and it worked as expected.

Your code:

```
<h1> <img src="nasa.png" width=110px height=92px> Apollo 11 mission </h1>
```

Correct code:

```
<h1> <img src="Nasa.png" width=110px height=92px> Apollo 11 mission </h1>
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer